# How to model an ALB with multiple certificates in AWS EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I see a lot of posts in Stackoverflow relating to this subject, but I think they're not exactly the same.

Currently we have AWS ALBs with HTTPS listeners with multiple rules, and each listener rule is a `/path/*`. I know how to model that with Ingress Controller and Ingress objects now.

However our ALBs have have 2 certificate ARNs to serve two different domains. I know Ingress has this annotation now.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:certificate/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But how do I add another certificate?

Comment: Did you try passing it in the same annotation, but comma separated?

Comment: I did, and at least the `helm template` test passed. I'll try to apply the chart shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [this](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/#certificate-arn) syntax mentioned under multiple certificates, which works fine with helm.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the arn certificates with comma that k8s automagically identifies the correct certificate for each rule:

alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:certificate/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:certificate/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2222222222222